# Installing LLVM 3.5 on Ubuntu 14.10 works, but is in the wrong folder?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, llvm, apt

I'm trying to use LLVM in one of my projects, I apt-get'd from the stable branch [as suggested on this site](http://llvm.org/apt/). Now the problem is that it appears to be in the wrong folder? All of the llvm executables and includes are suffixed with the version (-3.5). For example, `llvm-config` is `llvm-config-3.5`, which supposedly isn't correct. 
Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: You can get LLVM directly from the Ubuntu repositories. I'm pretty sure 3.5 is in 14.10.

Comment: I think I did that on my last install, and it was the same result :/

Comment: If you install via the official repositories you will be fine. The external ones are trying to remain separate from the official one.

Comment: Is there any way that I can change my current ones from llvm-*-3.5 to just llvm-*? I'm using it on an open source project, so I'd prefer that it was the same as what people typically use.